# How to convert result of query into count aggregate of each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the result of the query:

```
      LNAME   |    LISTAGG
--------------+---------------
              | ALEX
 BAIRSTOW     |
 BROAD        | STUART
 BUTLER       |
 COOK         | ALAISTER,ALEX
 HALES        | ALEX
 JENNINGS     |
--------------+---------------
(7 rows)
```

I would like to take result in 0, 1 or count of entries in the row like (ALAISTER,ALEX) are 2 and empty format.

So the output should be like:

```
  LNAME   |    LFNAME     | LNAME_COUNT  | LFNAME_COUNT
----------+---------------+--------------+-------------
 BROAD    | STUART        | 1            |   1
 BAIRSTOW |               | 1            |   0
 COOK     | ALAISTER,ALEX | 1            |   2
          | ALEX          | empty        |   1
 JENNINGS |               | 1            |   empty
 HALES    | ALEX          | 1            |   1
 BUTLER   |               | 1            |   0
----------+---------------+--------------+-------------
(7 rows)
```

I've used a case expression, but couldn't break out the (ALAISTER,ALEX) part.

Comment: Rather than just showing us the result of your current query, could you also show us that query along with the input data?

Comment: What dbms you use now?

Comment: Why  `JENNINGS |   | 1  | empty`  but  `BUTLER   |   | 1  | 0`  ?

Comment: There are some empty data and some null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can do this using `LEN()`.

```
SELECT LNAME, LISTAGG AS LFNAME,
       CASE WHEN LNAME IS NULL THEN CAST(0 AS VARCHAR (5))
            WHEN LEN(LNAME) > 1 THEN CAST((LEN(LNAME) - LEN(REPLACE(LNAME, ',', ''))) + 1 AS VARCHAR (5))
       ELSE 'empty' END AS LNAME_COUNT,
       CASE WHEN LISTAGG IS NULL THEN CAST(0 AS VARCHAR (5))
            WHEN LEN(LISTAGG) > 1 THEN CAST((LEN(LISTAGG) - LEN(REPLACE(LISTAGG, ',', ''))) + 1 AS VARCHAR (5)) 
       ELSE 'empty' END AS LFNAME_COUNT
FROM TableName
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle for SQL Server**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0df94f6859d52eef4c2dcdaf725385ed)

If your DBMS is MySQL, simply change the `LEN()` to `LENGTH()`

Answer (score 0):

The following query will do what you are looking for

```
     Declare @table table ( lname  varchar (20),   listagg varchar (20));

insert into @table ( lname , listagg ) values
(''        , 'alex'),
('bairstow', null),
('broad'   , 'stuart'),
('butler'  , ''),
('cook'    , 'alaister,alex'),
('hales'   , 'alex'),
('jennings', null);

 select 
  lname,
  listagg as LFName,
  case when lname <>'' then len(lname)-len(replace(lname,',',''))+1 else 0 end as LName_count,
  case when listagg <>'' then len(listagg)-len(replace(listagg,',',''))+1 else 0 end  as LFName_count
  from @table
```